# Does lowering the share difficulty allows me to find more blocks?

Tags: mining, parity

Lets assume that I've a very powerful server with very fast internet connection (32GB RAM, 4GBit/s upload and download) which runs `MiningCore` and `Parity` for private mining.

1. Does decreasing the `Share Difficulty`, allows me to find more blocks? If I decrease it, I know that way more shares will be submitted and my server can process them.
2. Storing the `DagFile` in SSD makes any difference OR it affects processing shares?
3. Storing the `Blockchain` data in SSD makes any difference OR it affects processing shares?

Comment: By decreasing the difficulty you can surely increase the number of mined block (BUT difficulty is an adaptive parameter, i.e. it is designed to reach a stable point that generates blocks at a constant rate) you can either modify the source code or trying to use proof of authority or other consensus algorithms in general.

Answer (score 1):

1. Initially, you can mine blocks fastly. In the end, however, the timestamp between blocks will become similar. ( 10~15 second per a block because of mining algorithm)
2. There will be no big difference. ( SSD is slightly better ??)
3. There will be no big difference. ( SSD is slightly better ??)

2~3: SSD is waiting for mining result, so there is not much relationship with blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

The mining algorithm will adjust after if you mine blocks too fast to ensure an equilibrium is reached where the blocks aren't too easy or too difficult to mine. For reference, here is the wiki:

> The difficulty dynamically adjusts so that on average one block is produced by the entire network every 12 seconds (ie., 12 s block time). This heartbeat basically punctuates the synchronisation of system state and guarantees that maintaining a fork (to allow double spend) or rewriting history is impossible unless the attacker possesses more than half of the network mining power (so called 51% attack).

[Ethereum Wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Mining#so-what-is-mining-anyway)